# Getting a 503 error but there's nothing in the Apache error log

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm getting a 503 error whenever I try to request any page. I really don't know how to go about fixing this problem. I've checked the error.log and this is what it contains:

```
[Fri Jan 13 19:03:41 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 13 19:03:51 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17 with     Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 13 19:08:59 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 13 19:09:41 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 13 19:11:59 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 13 19:12:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 13 19:13:03 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 13 19:13:14 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 14 11:25:28 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Jan 14 11:26:10 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 14 11:34:34 2012] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

I assume this is just reporting that I've rebooted the server from the AWS console.

Comment: Phew, fixed!

For the benefit of others, the 503 error seems to have been caused by my elastic load balancer not having any healthy instances to route requests to. This was because the URL I'd been using to check for health was throwing some database errors. I simply changed the health check ping target to a path that was working and everything started working again.

Answer (score 3):

This error code 503 means **Service Unavailable**. This is a temporary error and it can occur in several cases. For example, if a proxy server between your client and your server can not access your server for some reason, it may return this error. If you have an HTTP load balancer without any up (available) backend servers, you may get this error and so on. I think it may occur also due to timeout when trying to reach your server.

So, you need to check the path between your clients and your web server.

Comment: Thanks, that narrows it down a bit. How could I narrow it down further? For example, if it was a problem with my load balancer, how would I know? Everything looks fine in my aws console.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and also no error is goes to error_log.

I fix it by editing our .htacess file by removing some deny clause like below :
deny from 61.160.247.192/27

This code never cause problem before, so I still try to figure out why this cause problem now.